# Android Studio Clicking on "Project Structure " not working

Tags: android-studio

I have met a strange question about Android Studio and I have tried to find a solution on the Internet but it failed.

Here is my question:
I open the Android Studio and the project can be installed to my device correctly. However, when I tried to open the Project Structure, it failed without any response. I just clicked on the button below but the Project Structure dialog didn't show up:
[image]

I have SDK installed below:
[image]

Please help me how to open the Project Structure dialog.

Comment: Have you found a  solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a method to avoid my problem. My way is that uninstalling my sdk which version is Android 4.4. After doing that my project structure shows up. try deleting your current sdk for an attempt.